# Is tensorflow session running in parallel to the rest of my code?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I'm running my session on a GPU and I'm wondering if the 'session.run()' piece of code is running in parallel to my other code in my script. 
I use batch processing on the CPU prior to running 'session.run()' in a loop and would like to pipeline this processing with the execution on the GPU. Is this already satisfied in this setting or do I need to manually start threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out that 'session.run' is not running concurrently to your other code. Indeed, as Ujjwal suggested, the 'tf.data.Dataset' API is the best choice for pipelining batch preprocessing and GPU execution.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends upon how you have written your code. This should be trivial to check, by checking out your CPU  and GPU utilization simultanously

I normally make use of `tf.data.Dataset` API. I use the `get_next()` method of an iterator to feed data to a network. CPU and GPU work in parallel in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with 'tf.data.Dataset'. 
I am working on a cluster and have restricted rights, so it isn't easy or even impossible for me to check CPU/GPU utilization. 
My question however is a fundamental one: "Is tensorflow's session starting a seperate concurrent thread to any other code (non-tensorflow)?